# ReactJS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The code below gives the next error. I've set the header. I found the problem lies in CORS but couldn't find how to make it work. In the commented I tried to send request with axios but below the request is made with XMLHttpRequest which I though takes care of cors.

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
//import axios from 'axios';

export default class GoogleAuth extends React.Component<{}, {}>{
  constructor(props: {}){
    super(props);

    this.handleResponse = this.handleResponse.bind(this);
  }

  handleResponse(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.googleId);

    //if(response.googleId){
      // let config = {
      //   headers: {
      //     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      //     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
      //   },
      //
      // };
      //
      // axios.get('https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/' + response.googleId + '?kind=album&access=public', config)
      // .then(function(response2){
      //   console.log(response2);
      // })
      // .catch(function(error){
      //   console.log(error);
      // });

    //}

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        console.log(this);
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200){
          console.log(this.response);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open('get', 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/' + response.googleId + '?kind=album&access=public',true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="890876118034-jra8v99vqbgf3e0u5eu29lit2bm66lqi.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={this.handleResponse}
        onFailure={this.handleResponse}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow the whitelist header "http://localhost:3000" on you Google developer account.

or

Try changing the `dataType: 'jsonp'` in your ajax call.

Comment: I didn't get how to change dataType, but I installed and used jsonp, with "npm install jsonp --save". It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, since you have no control of the data that is being send by the server is to use [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). It adds CORS to the data that is being send from the server.

There is a preconfigured heroku app for cors-anywhere at this [link](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/).

You can change your axios call to

```
  axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/' + response.googleId + '?kind=album&access=public', config)
   .then(function(response2){
     console.log(response2);
   })
   .catch(function(error){
     console.log(error);
   });
```

so that you'll get a CORS header to the response.